# get sent mails via imap

Tags: c#, email, imap

Does someone know how I can get all sent mails to specific user using [AE.NET mail](https://github.com/andyedinborough/aenetmail) library?

I've tried something like this:

```
imap = new ImapClient(imapMailServer, username, password, ImapClient.AuthMethods.Login, imapMailPort, imapUseSSL);

if (imap.IsConnected)
{
    imap.SelectMailbox("INBOX");

    var msg = imap.SearchMessages(SearchCondition.To("examplemail@gmail.com"));
}
```

But without any success (msg collection is empty)...

**EDIT (SOLUTION)**:

I had to select sent folder instead of inbox. Because I am using gmail, Gmail's sent mail folder is named "[Gmail]/Sent Mail". So it has to be:

```
imap.SelectMailbox("[Gmail]/Sent Mail");
```

Comment: I was able to use your exact code with that library to connect to my Gmail account and search for messages with known `To` addresses. It looks like you may have some configuration issues.

Comment: Are you looking for message *you've* sent?  In that case, they're likely in the Sent folder (whatever that is).

Comment: Yes I'm looking for messages I've sent. But imap.SelectMailbox("Sent"); returns an error.

Comment: Ohh, gmail's sent mail folder is named "[Gmail]/Sent Mail". Ok it works like a charm. Thanks Max

Comment: I'll promote my comment to an answer.

Comment: @koste did you find a valid solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for message you've sent? In that case, they're likely in the Sent folder, which is `[Gmail]/Sent Mail` on Google.