# get Sent mail using IMAP

Tags: c#, asp.net, null, imap, gmail-imap

I'm trying to **fetch my sent mail** using **IMAP** in **C#** but even after a considerable amount of time, i've not been able to make it work.

The output given to me is **null** even when 12 emails are fetched. Consider the following screenshot

[image]

The only help/hint i got on stackoverflow is this:

- [get sent mails via imap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16444860/get-sent-mails-via-imap)

[UPDATE]

This is my code:

```
>             ImapClient client = new ImapClient("ExampleHost", port, ssl);
>             try
>             {
>                 client.Login("ExampleEmail", "ExamplePass", AuthMethod.Login);
>                 IEnumerable<uint> units = client.Search(SearchCondition.Seen());
>                 DataTable TempTaskTable = new DataTable();
>                 TempTaskTable.Columns.Add("FromEmail", typeof(string));
>                 TempTaskTable.Columns.Add("ToEmail", typeof(string));
>                 TempTaskTable.Columns.Add("Subject", typeof(string));
>               
>                 foreach (var uid in units)
>                 {
>                     System.Net.Mail.MailMessage email = client.GetMessage(uid,true, "[Gmail]/Sent Mail");
>                     DataRow TempTaskRow2 = TempTaskTable.NewRow();
>                     TempTaskRow2["FromEmail"] = email.Sender;
>                     TempTaskRow2["ToEmail"] = email.From;
>                     TempTaskRow2["Subject"] = email.Subject;
>                 }
>                 bool result = false;
>                 string msg = "";
>                 usp_TempTasksSave(TempTaskTable, TempTaskAttachmentDatatTable, out result, out msg);
>             }
>             catch (Exception ex)
>             {
>                 string exceptionCheck = ex.Message;
>             }
```

Any sort of help would really be appreciated.

Comment: Please post the relevant code itself, a screenshot of half a loop is not enough for anyone on SO to assist you.

Comment: @G0Dsquad I've updated my answer.