# Issues fetching sent Mail using IMAP in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, email, imap

I'm using IMAP to get the my mail from gmail. It fetches the emails from inbox fine but when it comes to sent mail, provides null values.

This the code which i'm using:

```
ImapClient client = new ImapClient("ExampleHost", port, ssl);
try
{
    client.Login("ExampleEmail", "ExamplePass", AuthMethod.Login);
    IEnumerable<uint> units = client.Search(SearchCondition.Seen());
    DataTable TempTaskTable = new DataTable();
    TempTaskTable.Columns.Add("FromEmail", typeof(string));
    TempTaskTable.Columns.Add("ToEmail", typeof(string));
    TempTaskTable.Columns.Add("Subject", typeof(string));
    foreach (var uid in units)
    {
        System.Net.Mail.MailMessage email = client.GetMessage(uid,true, "[Gmail]/Sent Mail");
        DataRow TempTaskRow2 = TempTaskTable.NewRow();
        TempTaskRow2["FromEmail"] = email.Sender;
        TempTaskRow2["ToEmail"] = email.From;
        TempTaskRow2["Subject"] = email.Subject;
    }

    bool result = false;
    string msg = "";
    usp_TempTasksSave(TempTaskTable, TempTaskAttachmentDatatTable, out result, out msg);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    string exceptionCheck = ex.Message;
}
```

and this is my output:

[image]

I have also searched on stackoverflow and so far this is the only help which i've got yet Insufficient

- [get Sent mail using IMAP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41463400/get-sent-mail-using-imap)

Any sort of help would really be appreciated.

Comment: Try something like `foreach (var folder in client.Inbox.GetSubfolders (false)) { Console.WriteLine ("[folder] {0}", folder.Name); }`  to see if you are using the right name for the folder

Comment: @kraangPrime it says that the IMAP does not contain a definition for 'Inbox' and no extension method 'Inbox' accepting a first argument as type of IMAPClient could be found.

Comment: @kraangPrime I've verified the folder name and its the right one. "[Gmail]/Sent Mail".

Comment: Which Library are you using for `ImapClient`  ?

Comment: @kraangPrime actually this is somebody else's code which i'm trying to configure and i'm not sure which library was used in it.

Comment: Check (and add to the question) the `using`'s at the top of the `.cs` file please. Hard to troubleshoot a library when we don't know which library you are using.  It looks like it could be [AE.Net Mail](https://github.com/andyedinborough/aenetmail)

Comment: @kraangPrime apologies for the inconvenience. Its using S22.Imap i guess.

Comment: Could you please provide a stack trace of the `email` variable from `System.Net.Mail.MailMessage email = client.GetMessage(uid,true, "[Gmail]/Sent Mail"`and the`TempTaskRow2 ` variable from `DataRow TempTaskRow2 = TempTaskTable.NewRow();` - also, try the code on [this page](http://smiley22.github.io/S22.Imap/Documentation/html/M_S22_Imap_ImapClient_GetMailboxInfo.htm) and show the output please.

Comment: @kraangPrime i solved the issue, Thank you for your time!

Comment: @kraangPrime i didn't specify the DEFAULT MAILBOX at the start which is required. In my case, it always took the default mailbox as 'INBOX' and hence, failing to get the sent mail. I only had to add a line to make it work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the issue by setting the default mailbox. **In my case, the default mailbox was always INBOX** due to which i was not able to fetch the sent mail. it took a single line to solve the issue. This is the code which i'm using now:

```
ImapClient client = new ImapClient("ExampleHost", port, ssl);
client.DefaultMailbox = "[Gmail]/Sent Mail";
try
{
    client.Login("ExampleEmail", "ExamplePass", AuthMethod.Login);
    IEnumerable<uint> units = client.Search(SearchCondition.Seen());
    DataTable TempTaskTable = new DataTable();
    TempTaskTable.Columns.Add("FromEmail", typeof(string));
    TempTaskTable.Columns.Add("ToEmail", typeof(string));
    TempTaskTable.Columns.Add("Subject", typeof(string));
    foreach (var uid in units)
    {
        System.Net.Mail.MailMessage email = client.GetMessage(uid,true, "[Gmail]/Sent Mail");
        DataRow TempTaskRow2 = TempTaskTable.NewRow();
        TempTaskRow2["FromEmail"] = email.Sender;
        TempTaskRow2["ToEmail"] = email.From;
        TempTaskRow2["Subject"] = email.Subject;
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    string exceptionCheck = ex.Message;
}
```

You can also see all of your mailboxes using:

```
List<String> mailBoxesCheck = new List<string>();
foreach (var folder in client.ListMailboxes())
{
   mailBoxesCheck.Add(folder);
}
```

Comment: If you want to convert to a `List<>` type you can simply call `client.ListMailboxes().ToList()` as it is a `string[]` array.   For debugging, you can just log the output using `Console.Log( folder )` instead of `mailBoxesCheck.Add(folder);` .   :)

Comment: There are efficient ways yes @kraangPrime :)